# Hardness of approximation of the 3 colorability problem

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, approximation

If we have polynomial algorithm that $c$-approximation, $c<\frac{4}{3}$ for graphs that their chromatic number $\geq k$ then $NP=P$, how to prove such statements?

I also have some sort of explanation of this statement: It's NP-hard to separate between graphs that have chromatic number $k$ and chromatic number $c \cdot k$ when $c<\frac{4}{3} \quad \forall k\geq 3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  Consider planar graphs.

Comment: I know about hardness of coloring planar graphs with 3 colors while if we consider 4 colors then the problem is trivial also 2 colors if easy to achieve , what I want is a proof of the statement because I didnt understand it well in the class !!

Comment: Well, if you had a polytime $c$-approximation number for the chromatic number then you could apply it to planar graphs and ...?

Comment: so if we have c-approximation for $c<\frac43$ then if the graph is 3-colorable the approximation would give a number $k<4$ and if it is 4-colorable then it would give a number $k_1 < \frac{16}3$ so we could solve the 3 colorability for planar graphs all we have to do is to check the boundaries ??

Comment: More or less. You have to explain how exactly to use this hypothetical approximation algorithm.

Comment: Maybe I am being dense, but I do not see why you need to talk about planar graphs at all. All you need to know is that it's NP-hard to distinguish graphs with chromatic number 3 and graphs with chromatic number greater than 3, i.e. at least 4.

Comment: @Sasho How do you know that's true? It's not true if you replace 3 with 2. Of course, with my method you need to know that 3COL is hard even for planar graphs.

Comment: think of *any* Karp reduction to 3COL (i.e. the decision problem "given $G$, is $G$ 3 colorable?"). on yes instances (of say 3SAT, but that does not matter), the reduction produces a 3-colorable graph. on no instances the reduction produces a graph that is not 3-colorable. because 1-colorable and 2-colorable graphs are 3 colorable, the reduction must produce a graph with chromatic number at least 4. anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: unless you defined 3COL as "$\chi(G) = 3$?" rather than "$\chi(G) \leq 3$?", but that does not matter since the first is reducible to the second. BTW what makes me more uncomfortable about your argument is (I think) you suggest using the 4CT. this reminds me of a the a proof I saw on MO: 56 is not a cube, proof by the FLT: $56 = 64 - 8 = 4^3 - 2^3$ ;)